# Reporting Services - Working with the same reports across different databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have a Reporting services project that has a number of reports in the the report folder and a Live, Test and Dev data source in the Shared Data Source folder.

I have set up the solution configurations to deploy to different folders on the server based on the config (eg. debug -> dev).

My problem is that i need the reports in the dev folder on the server to use the dev datasource, the test reports to use the test datasource and the live reports to use the live datasource.

What is the best approach to take?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the datasources in different folders too.

You can configure the RS project datasource folder as well as for RDLs, so you can keep the same name for the datasource.

Comment: This is what i did in the end. I created a datasource folder in each test folder and gave the datasource a common name and just modified the db each one looked at.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you create a reporting site per environment with the same folder structure and use data sources with the same name in all three places pointing to the appropriate database.

Comment: This was a consideration i made but because of reasons out of my control, it was ruled out.